# How to combine Heatmap actual values and heatmap that is colored based on a row?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I created two separate heatmaps, the first one shows the actual values but colors the heatmap comparing all values in the heat map. The second one colors the heatmap based on the values in each row that I want to see. Now, I would like to have actual values from frist heatmap, but keep the coloring from the second one. Below are screnshots of the heatmaps and the codes I used.

First I created the pivot table:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(table, 'avg', index = ['col_1'], columns = ['col_2'])
```

Then I created first heatmap:

```
sns.heatmap(df, linewidths=.5, annot = True, cbar=False, fmt='g', annot_kws = {'size':14}, cmap='YlOrBr');
```

[image: First heatmap]

And then I created the second heatmap:

```
df_n = df.div(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
sns.heatmap(df_n, linewidths=.5, annot = True, annot_kws = {'size':14}, cbar=True, fmt='g', cmap='YlOrBr')
```

[image: Second heatmap]

Comment: The data=` parameter takes care of the color, with `annot=...` you have the option to set other values for the annotation: `sns.heatmap(data=df_n, annot=df, ...)`

Comment: @JohanC, can you help me with scientific numbers as well? I set "fmt='g'" in my heatmap, but it's not working. It still shows some numbers in scientific type. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `fmt='.0f'` to show them as numbers without decimals?

Comment: @JohanC you're awesome! One Python beginner appreciates your help very much! Cheers!